# How do I speed up ContentEditable td input speed in large tables in Chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, contenteditable, mobile-chrome

I have an web app that has a table for data entry. Each row has 16 columns, of which 14 are editable. This table for some users can reach over 100 rows. What I'm running into, is on Chrome Mobile, once it gets to over ~50 rows, it starts getting really slow, and by 80+ rows its to around 1 character per second to enter text into any cell. It works fine on firefox, safari, and is only slightly slow on mobile Edge. I made a stripped down version on codepen with a small table, and a large table and got the same results with the same results, so it can't be anything else in my page.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

  <style>
    td, th {
      width: 60px
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
  <style/>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>C1</th>
        <th>C2</th>
        <th>C3</th>
        <th>C4</th>
        <th>C5</th>
        <th>C6</th>
        <th>C7</th>
        <th>C8</th>
        <th>C9</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='tbody1'>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">Mary</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">had</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">a</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">little</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">lamb</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">whose</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">fleece</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">was</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">white</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br><br>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>C1</th>
        <th>C2</th>
        <th>C3</th>
        <th>C4</th>
        <th>C5</th>
        <th>C6</th>
        <th>C7</th>
        <th>C8</th>
        <th>C9</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='tbody2'>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true">Mary</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">had</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">a</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">little</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">lamb</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">whose</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">fleece</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">was</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">white</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    element = document.querySelector("#tbody1");
    element.innerHTML +=  
      "<tr>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>Mary</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>had</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>a</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>little</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>lamb</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>whose</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>fleece</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>was</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>white</td>" + 
      "</tr>"; 
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    element = document.querySelector("#tbody2");
    element.innerHTML +=  
      "<tr>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>Mary</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>had</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>a</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>little</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>lamb</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>whose</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>fleece</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>was</td>" + 
        "<td contenteditable='true'>white</td>" + 
      "</tr>"; 
  }

}
</script>

</body>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Tbuerge/pen/jOPLPeR)

I have tried making only the cell I'm currently editing editable, but that doesn't seem to make any diffence.

Comment: Have you tried to make the `tbody` contenteditable instead of the individual cells? Actually, I couldn't reproduce the issue when trying the Codepen snippet on Android phone.

Comment: I haven't, I don't want rows and columns editable, and not all cells are editable. Did you scroll down far enough to get to the second, big table? The first one is 20 rows, the second is 200.

Comment: Scrolled to the last row, no problems. But creting the table as many times as it has rows is deadslow.

Comment: I wonder why it's so slow for me then. I just tried again, and it's about .8 seconds per letter, entry speed. I know the way created those tables was terrible. I was just too lazy to actually try a build it all correctly.

Comment: iOS or android?

Comment: I'm on Android.

Comment: Well this is really crazy. I had tested that on my daily user phone, and my development testing phone, and both were slow. I pulled out my half dead junker phone, it was just as fast as anything else. Now I'm confused.

Comment: I just retested, with the same results. Cleared caches on everything and made sure nothing was running in the background. On my "fast" phone it was really slow. On my slow phone, it normal.

Comment: @TroyBuerge are the chrome versions the same on those phones?

Comment: Yes. The only real difference I can think of is Android version and hardware. I even tried running in safe mode to make sure there wasn't another app screwing with it.

Comment: I just updated both phones, now the problem one is on 80.0.3987.119 and the other is 80.0.3987.132. I wonder if its a motorola or android one bug? any chance?

Comment: The only way to optimize is to reduce the total number of rows in your big table. Try some virtual scrolling techniques. Say use one tr element with some fixed height to replace all the tr elements outside browser window.